# Tomcat 9 starts on terminal [ubuntu 18.04] but does not load in browser

Tags: linux, tomcat, ubuntu-18.04, tomcat9

On running startup.sh, this is the output shown

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

Followed this step by step for installation: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-tomcat-ubuntu

Opened the port using

```
sudo ufw allow 8080/tcp
sudo ufw allow 8080
```

`netstat -tunlp | grep java` gives this:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      13705/java          
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      13705/java
```

But the http://ip:8008 does not show up the tomcat home page.

I am able to view the apache homepage at http://ip after apache2 installation but tomcat doesn't seem to work at all.

There is no error in catalina.out, last line says this

```
15-Jun-2020 23:10:05.846 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [1,223] milliseconds
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Is it because I have both apache and tomcat running? do i need to change port?

Comment: From your browser you need to connect to port 8080 not 8008 as you have mentioned. If you have access to the server try curl command too ```http://localhost:8080```   If you have multiple nic's replace localhost with ip of those nic's

Comment: 8008 was a typo.. i had used 8080

Answer (score 1):

Access application using `http://127.0.0.1:8080` and test. If you want to access the application on IP address then add IP address in server.xml file and test.

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" address="IP-address" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: doesn't help even if i change it

Comment: Share your connector configuration from server.xml. which URL accessed in the browser? Instead of browser could you please access using `curl` command and test.

Comment: curt http://localhost:8080 works fine.
curl http://ip-addr:8080 doesn't come back with response

Comment: Looks like tomcat works on loopback(127.0.0.1). Could you please share server.xml file content in answer. are you using your tomcat-server IP address in server.xml.Restart tomcat after suggested changes and test.

Comment: this is my connector string
 <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" 
               address="0.0.0.0" />
I have tried adding the exact ip in address as well as you suggested for address=

Comment: Could you please add the exact IP in server.xml. Restart Tomcat service and share netstat and curl command output. `netstat -tunlp | grrep :8080` `curl http://IP-Address:8080`

Comment: Looks like you are using wrong IP address. Could you please check IP address of tomcat server and then use it in server.xml file.

Comment: You can check server IP adress using `ifconfig ` or `ip r l` command.

Comment: nope.. i had changed the version of tomcat too but it didn't work.

I thought of adding my local ip instead of 127.0.0.1 in etc/hosts file.. but I am yet to try that. In server.xml, for address="ip-address". is it external ip or internal ip?

Comment: You can use internal IP in the server.xml file. Make sure that tomcat started on internal IP. Then first access using curl command.

Comment: it didn't.. i took a vm with tomcat image now, it came with tomcat auto enabled.. thanks for trying to help